# GNU make: rule prequisites in nested variables not executed

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The point is that I want to have some dependencies centralized in one variable, but the dependencies themselves are contained in variables.

```
    a=meow
    b=squeek

    $(a):
        touch $@
    $(b):
        touch $@

    targs=$(a) $(b)

    all: $(targs)
```

In the real case rules for a and b differ so I need them to be in separate targets.

When I try to build such a target, only last nested dependency gets executed:

```
    $ make
    touch meow

    $ ls
    . .. Makefile meow
```

Could anyone please explain me how do I fix the situation or where I'm wrong?
I can make a phony target like targs: $(a) $(b), but if there's a way to keep the structure I mentioned, I'd like to know about it.

Thanks in advance!

UPD: solved. My mistake: instead of running `make all` I ran `make` and make executed the first target instead of `all`.

Comment: Works for me. Did you check indentation issue(spaces instead of tab) in receipt for `$(b)`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, my mistake. I was running 'make' and it ran the first rule i.e. $(a).
When I ran `make all` it worked properly.

Comment: Oh, you use `make` with *default* target, but default target is the first one listed in the makefile. Try `make all` or move `all` rule above other ones in the makefile.

Comment: Okay, it was my mistake. The problem is the order of rules. Just the same mistake in the real Makefile as in the example:)

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yay, understood it right now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make's default is to use the first target in the Makefile.  Either move the *all* target to the beginning or use the following line somewhere in your Makefile

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```